# R - Grouping rows based on the values of one column

Tags: r, grouping

I have observed plant leaf number (column 'No. of fully expanded leaves") of different plant (Plant id) on different days (Measuring date). I want to group plants with the same maximum No. of fully expanded leaves (with all columns included) and put them in the same spreadsheet, which means plants with different max leaves will be put into separate files. Here is what my data look like:

[image]

And here is what the data of a single plant looks like:

[image]

How can I do this in R?

Many thanks,

Comment: Please share the data itself, not just pictures of it.

Comment: Welcome to SO!, please read and follow posting guidelines of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also include output of `dput(head(DF))` where `DF` is your input `data.frame`

Comment: plantid <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: I think you need `split`